# Unsplash API integration in CakePHP

Tags: api, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Can any one suggest me how to integrate UnSplash API in cakePHP.

I have already downloaded lib and paste it in vendor folder.But further more please suggest any one.

I have downloaded lib reference from https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation of unsplash. If you want to get only images then no need to use authentication of unsplash . You can easly get images after hitting API with app id like this:

https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=YOUR_APPLICATION_ID

So if anyone want to implement search for getting images only developer can access api like this :

https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=1&query=office&client_id=YOUR_APPLICATION_ID

By this you can easily get images and no authorisation required. Further if you want to use more feature then you can use auth of particular unsplash user.